# Boolean logic and types in haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I'm currently having Haskell for university. Given the following haskell code:

```
true::t -> t1 -> t
true = (\x y -> x)

false::t -> t1 -> t1
false = (\x y -> y)

-- Implication
(==>) = (\x y -> x y true)
```

The task is to determine the type of the function `(==>)`.
GHCi says it is `(==>) :: (t1 -> (t2 -> t3 -> t2) -> t) -> t1 -> t`.

I can see that the evaluation order is the following (as the type stays the same):

```
(==>) = (\x y -> (x y) true)
```

So the function `true` ist argument to `(x y)`.

Can anyone explain why the result type t is bound to the result of the first argument and in which way GHCi determines the type of `(==>)`?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://lucacardelli.name/Papers/BasicTypechecking.pdf It explains the basic algorithm that GHC uses to infer and check types of things (obviously the real algorithm is more complex, but this works for your example)

Comment: The return type of x is the return type of ==> because x is the outermost function, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, to give a better overview,

```
type True t f = t -> f -> t
type False t f = t -> f -> f
```

Let's call the result of the implication `r`, then we have, in `\x y -> x y true :: r`, that

```
x y :: True t f -> r
```

so `x :: y -> True t f -> r`, and thus

```
(==>) :: (y -> True t f -> r) -> y -> r
```

which, expanding `True` again, is

```
(==>) :: (y -> (t->f->t) -> r) -> y -> r
```

Comment: And because y is the arguement to x, it appears again as the type of the second parameter, because it must be the same?